# Help needed with a Calculus/Vector question

Tags: calculus, vectors, surface-integrals

this is my question, any help would be appreciated.

Consider the vector $D= 3 \sin(\theta)$ ar   (unit vector).

Evaluate the integral $$\iint_S D ~dS,$$
where $S$ is the surface of a sphere with radius $r=5$ centered at the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of polar coordinates, the surface area element at constant $r$, in your case $r=5$, is $r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$. Let $\hat{n}$ denote the unit vector parallel to, $D$ so your integral is$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi d\theta r^2\sin\theta D\cdot\hat{n}=150\pi\int_0^\pi\sin^2\theta d\theta=75\pi^2.$$

Comment: are we not supposed to use the vector D in the calculations at all?

Comment: @Aslanova I did; it provided a factor of $3\sin\theta$.

Comment: oh I missed that, thanks a lot!!